# Adding a feature to an already complex query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table which logs chat messages

```
CREATE TABLE public.message_log
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('message_log_id_seq'::regclass),
  message text,
  from_id character varying(500),
  to_id character varying(500),
  match_id character varying(500),
  unix_timestamp bigint,
  own_account boolean,
  reply_batch boolean DEFAULT false,
  insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT message_log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT message_log_message_from_id_to_id_match_id_unix_timestamp_key UNIQUE (message, from_id, to_id, match_id, unix_timestamp)
)
```

A chat conversation has the same `match_id`

I have the following query which returns a list of match_ids which the last message related to the match_id (the last message of the chat conversation) is from the non account holder (own_account = false) the query is working fine

```
select m.* from message_log m where m.from_id <> ? and m.to_id = ? and m.unix_timestamp = 
( 
select max(unix_timestamp) from message_log where match_id = m.match_id group by match_id 
)
```

I want to modify the query above that it would count the chat conversations that have had been replied to twice or more (I think we would need to use the `reply_batch` column). I can not get my mind around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample data, current and desired output would be great. Could you provide that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT match_id, replies_count FROM (SELECT match_id, COUNT(*) AS replies_count FROM message_log
WHERE from_id <> ? and to_id = ? GROUP BY match_id) AS replies_counter WHERE replies_count > 1
```

Comment: That's not going to work as `replies_count` column doesn't exist. In `WHERE` section you can filter only real columns.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Query edited, please try again